# Jquery code to simple javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Thanks for your help in advance. I want this jquery code to be converted to core js code. I'm developing an angularJs app. This code most of time doesn't work. this is why I want to change it to 
This is my jquery code

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        console.log('jquery');

        var trigger = $('.hamburger'),
                overlay = $('.overlay'),
                isClosed = false;

        $('.hamburger').click(function ()
        {
            hamburger_cross();
        });

        function hamburger_cross()
        {
            console.log('trigger');

            if (isClosed == true) {
                overlay.hide();
                trigger.removeClass('is-open');
                trigger.addClass('is-closed');
                isClosed = false;
            } else {
                overlay.show();
                trigger.removeClass('is-closed');
                trigger.addClass('is-open');
                isClosed = true;
            }
        }
        ;

        $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function () {
            $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');
        });
    });
</script>
```

The only reason I am not able to use the above code is it use code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js "The jquery library" I want to remove this link because it is causing other conflicts. I will be very thankful if someone converts it to simple javascript.

Comment: Please don't post "please-do-my-work" requests like this. Try to do it by yourself and if you're stuck on a specific problem, ask for the solution.

Comment: i have tried my best.

Comment: Well, post your current state and errors encountered so that we could help, but currently, this is too much vague.

Comment: @MirzaSisic Thanks buddy, You are helpful in all crowd of hatred. All others are just dislikers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we can't help you by writting all code. But checkout this website you will find so many references to your code. http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/. Hope this will help you out.